# How to disable transitive dependencies in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

If I am creating a package(P1) that depends on other packages(p2 and p3) to be used by other app(A1). How can I stop app(A1) from accessing transitive dependencies(p2 and p3)?

```
   A
   |
   |
   P1
   /\
  /  \
p2    p3
```

In android(gradle) we can selectively expose dependent packages by making use `implementation` and `api`.

in build.gradle of p1

```
implementation p2
api p3
```

in build.gradle of A1

```
implementation p1
```

This will make p3 available for use in A1 but p2 will not be available for use.

Is there a way to have a control on transitive dependencies in dart?

Comment: In a Dart package, A1 already must explicitly add P2 and P3 as `dependencies` in its `pubspec.yaml` file in order to use them.  If P1 wants to expose P3 as part of its API, it must explicitly `export` APIs from P3.

Comment: No @jamesdlin, as per my observation A1 can access the all dependencies declared in pubspec.yaml of P1.

Comment: ```Pub gets every package that your package depends on, and everything those packages depend on, transitively``` from https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies